# Ethereum wallet for Tor and Tails OS (Darknet users)

Tags: metamask, wallets, ethereum-wallet-dapp, tor, darkweb

Tor is a web browser for the darknet, while Tails OS, is an operating system that you install on a USB drive that leaves no traces on the computer itself after shut down. Browsing with Tor on the Tails OS is a common combination for Darknet users to retain their anonymity online.

Which ethereum wallet is most appropriate for use for Tor and Tails users, given that Tails wipes the entire session after shutdown? This means that **Tails will wipe clean any ethereum wallet installed**. Which ethereum wallet will survive this, perhaps as a perpetual installation, or by repeatedly recovering the wallet during next start-ups with its private key? **Metamask is a google chrome extension, which is a different browser than Tor**.

The point is to prevent the wallet from being disposable: we want to use it as our go-to wallet over the course of weeks if not months and years.

Comment: The Tor browser is just Firefox with certain restrictions included. You can install and use Metamask as you normally would, just re-seeding using your mnemonic each time you use it.

Comment: Note that if you're just using the Tor browser with a wallet extension _not_ through Tails, it's probable that the wallet traffic won't be via the browser's associated Tor relays (it'll probably be a direct connection).

Comment: so Tails, Tor + Metamask is the best way to go? and re-seed the mnemonic each start-up? You would have to re-install the Metamask firefox extension for Tor each time too though if running on Tails